# Padding trailing whitespaces in a string with another character

Tags: bash, shell, string, printf

I'd like to output **`hello world`** over 20 characters.

```
printf "%-20s :\n\n" 'hello world!!'

# Actual output
hello world!!        :

# Wanted output
hello world!!========:
```

However, I don't want to complete with spaces but with "**=**" instead.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Updated answer to be more general solution. see also [my another answer below](/a/399059/72456) using only shell brace expansion and `printf`.*

```
$ str='Hello World!'
$ sed -r ':loop; s/ (=*):$/\1=:/; t loop' <<< "$(printf '%-20s:\n' "$str" )"
Hello World!========:
```

**How it works?**

this  `(=*):$/` captures one space, one-or-more `=` that followed by a colon `:` in the end of its input; we make the set of `=` as a group match and `\1` will be its back-reference.

With `:loop` we defined a label named `loop` and with `t loop` it will jump to that label when a `s/ (=*):$/\1=:/` has done successful substitution;

In replacement part with `\1=:`, it will always increment the number of `=`s and back the colon itself to the end of string.

Comment: so you have to adjust the flag depending on how many words the input has?

Comment: @grawity I have updated my answer to general solution now.

Answer (score 23):

```
filler='===================='
string='foo'

printf '%s\n' "$string${filler:${#string}}"
```

Gives

```
foo=================
```

`${#string}` is the length of the value `$string`, and `${filler:${#string}}` is the substring of `$filler` from offset `${#string}` onwards.

The total width of the output will be that of the maximum width of `$filler` or `$string`.

The filler string can, on systems that has `jot`, be created dynamically using

```
filler=$( jot -s '' -c 16 '=' '=' )
```

(for 16 `=` in a line).  GNU systems may use `seq`:

```
filler=$( seq -s '=' 1 16 | tr -dc '=' )
```

Other systems may use Perl or some other faster way of creating the string dynamically.

Comment: @sddgob How would you do it with `printf` + brace expansion in `bash`?

Answer (score 16):

```
printf "%.20s:\n\n" "$str========================="
```

where `%.20s` is the string truncating format

Comment: This is IMHO, a better solution than mine. It only needs a short explanation of the format string.

Answer (score 11):

One way to do it:

```
printf "====================:\r%s\n\n" 'hello world!!'
```

Comment: Ha! That's a clever trick! However, it will actually print `====================\rhello world`, which might be an issue if the OP needs to store this and not just print it to screen.

Comment: also `echo -e '=================\rHello World!!'`, but has same issue as @terdon pointed that.

Comment: @αғsнιη Only if `echo` supports `-e`.  `printf` is almost always better than `echo`, for many reasons.

Answer (score 5):

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -le '$k="hello world!!"; while(length($k)<20){$k.="=";} print "$k\n"'
hello world!!=======
```

Or, better, @SatoKatsura pointed out in the comments:

```
perl -le '$k = "hello world!!"; print $k, "=" x (20-length $k), "\n"'
```

If you need to support UTF multi-byte characters, use:

```
PERL_UNICODE='AS' perl -le '$k = "hello world!!"; print $k, "=" x (20-length $k), "\n"'
```

Same idea in the shell:

```
v='hello world!!'; while [ ${#v} -lt 20 ]; do v="$v""="; done; printf '%s\n\n' "$v"
```

Comment: You don't need a loop: `perl -le '$k = "hello world!!"; print $k, "=" x (20-length $k), "\n"'`.  However, this (and all other solutions posted so far) breaks if multi-byte characters are involved.

Comment: @SatōKatsura ooh, yes, that's neat! Should have thought of that, thanks. And yes, I was thinking of adding a disclaimer for possible failure on UTF multi-byte characters, but figured it would be a needless complication in this context.

Comment: I think `perl6` might have a way to do it correctly even with multi-byte characters.  But on the other hand `perl6` is annoying in so many ways.

Comment: @SatōKatsura well, for this sort of simple thing, it should be enough to just set `PERL_UNICODE='AS'`. For example: `printf '%s' nóóös | perl -nle 'print length($_)'` prints 8 ("wrong") while `printf '%s' nóóös | PERL_UNICODE='AS' perl -nle 'print length($_)'` prints 5 ("correct").

Answer (score 5):

Another way is using only `printf` command and generate the character padding pattern first by [`Shell Brace Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) (You can put *end* with a number ≥ formatting area you want to print in `{1..end}`) and get only every first character of it `%.1s` which is `=`s and then print only first 20 characters length area of that `%.20s`. This is kind of better way to having repeated characters/word instead of duplicating them.

```
printf '%.20s:\n' "$str$(printf '%.1s' ={1..20})"
Hello World!!=======:
```

---

**Explanations:**

Normally as [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), shell expanding `{1..20}` as following if we print those.

```
printf '%s ' {1..20}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

So with adding an equal sign to it `={1..20}`, shell will expand as following.

```
printf '%s ' ={1..20}
=1 =2 =3 =4 =5 =6 =7 =8 =9 =10 =11 =12 =13 =14 =15 =16 =17 =18 =19 =20
```

And with `printf '%.1s'` which is actually means `printf '%WIDE.LENGTH'`, we are printing only one *LENGTH* of those at above with default `1` *WIDE*. so will result `=`s only and 20 times repeated itself.

Now with `printf '%.20s:\n'` we are printing only the 20 length of `$str` and if length of `$str`<20, the rest will take from generated `=`s to fill with instead of spaces.